# Open Subsets of $\Bbb R$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, inverse-function

Let $d$ be the usual Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R$ and $f\colon (\Bbb R, d) \to ([-1,1],d)$ be the map given by $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=\sin(\frac1x)$ if $x\neq0$.

Let $A$ be an open subset of $\Bbb R$ such that $0 \in A$. Show that $f[A] = [-1,1]$.

My idea is to construct a proof which shows that this mapping sends open sets into open sets but $\sin(\frac1x)$ is not continuous at $0 $. My question is, how can i show that $f[A] = [-1,1]$ since there is a discontinuity at $0$? Or does this not matter in this case?

Comment: It doesn't matter, the question only asks what the range of $f$ is. $f$ *is* continuous on $(0,+\infty)$ and on $(-\infty,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.**

What are the values of $f$ at points $\frac{1}{2 k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}$ and $\frac{1}{2 k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}}$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$?

Comment: The values will be in the interval of [-1,1].